# NPM warning node-fetch @2.6.7 Requires a peer of encoding@^0.1.0 but none was installed

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

NPM warning node-fetch @2.6.7
Requires a peer of encoding@^0.1.0 but none was installed.

Comment: `npm install encoding`

Answer (score 0):

peer dependency means that it need the library and you must install that dependency by yourself:

```
npm i encoding@0.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install appium using npm and got this error.

*npm install encoding* or even *npm i encoding@0.1.0* didn't work for me.
I dug around a little and found that I had node version 11 installed which didn't support installation of appium. Just upgraded the node version to a stable 16 and the appium installation worked.